# Suggestions for large nested map in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, hashmap, mutability

I need to aggregate a really large number of records according to two criteria. Let say for the sake of an example that the records say in which city a person was on an daily basis.

I need to do this aggregate with very limited hardware and no cloud. I do not want to upload the original data to a database for this, the original data is really large (think billions of records)

My original idea is to build a map with key a person id, it would be a few millions, and the value is a map where the key is the city and the value is the number of days they spent in that city. This is a map with millions of keys and each value having map a few tenths (less than 100) entries.

I want to run some benchmarks and I would like some help to shortlist the type of maps I can use: mutable / inmutable, hash/tree... I need to balance performance with memory usage too.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like your problem is going to be ingesting billions of records each time you start your app rather than how you store your data.

Comment: Correct, the raw records are discarded after aggregation. On a "real" system it would be different, but here I need to cope with very limited hardware.

Comment: I think i will share my findings, as of November 2018 scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[K, V] has worked well enough for us for single thread, for multi thread we are checking import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap (as Scala).

Comment: A final edit, for my problem I have found that a tail recursive function using inmutable maps and nested maps works essentially as fast as an iterative approach using mutable data structures. I am pleasantly surprised

Answer (score 0):

If performance is critical, you should consider using mutable data structures for aggregation process because immutability in Scala, especially in case of large records can cost you a significant performance drop. You can check this article, there are benchmarks for different collections as well:
https://medium.com/@hussachai/scalas-immutable-collections-can-be-slow-as-a-snail-da6fc24bc688

Also, you should consider using parallel collections to speed up records processing:
https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-parallel-collections-in-scala-performance

However, the memory usage may be the problem. Instead of keeping all of the data in memory at once you may want to implement a streaming solution or use, for instance, Apache Spark where you could persist your data on disk if it exceeds the memory limit

Comment: I have prepared a first implementation using mutable structures and I am impressed with the speed. Right now memory is the constraint, can you give me some pointers for the streaming approach?

Comment: I updated my answer, try to use Apache Spark - it is optimized for processing of huge amounts of data and has an ability to automatically cache your data on disk if it exceeds the memory limit. Also, it is optimized for parallel execution, so even on a single node with multi-core processor it will utilize all of the cores efficiently as well

Comment: Unfortunately Spark is not an option for us in this particular scenario.